# Почему не работает FTP сервер на windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ftp-сервер

Пытаюсь создать FTP сервер стандартными средствами windows 10.
Включил компонент винды "службы IIS", создал FTP сервер, указал в его привязках свой IP, разрешил в брандмауэре входящие и исходящие соединения FTP, в правилах авторизации FTP разрешил анонимным пользователям чтение, но никто не может получить доступ к моей папке.
Чтобы другие смогли её посмотреть им тоже нужно включить компонент "службы IIS"?
Чтобы получить доступ к папке нужна ведь только ссылка типа [ftp://мойIP](ftp://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9IP)?

Comment: Что конкретно означает фраза "не может получить доступ"? Ошибка подключения? Ошибка авторизации?

Comment: @andreymal "не удаётся получить доступ к сайту"

Comment: *создал FTP сервер* А настроил? корневую папку и прочие причиндалы указал? безопасность там. юзеров создать... *указал в его привязках свой IP* Сперва укажи локалхост да с него самого достучись, потом уже извне пробовать будешь.

Comment: @Akina да, указал корневую папку, и я могу посмотреть её содержимое сам по ссылке 
  ftp: // мойIP, а другие не могут

Comment: Похоже, где-то что-то недонастроил в антивирусах-файрволах. Проверь, слушается ли 21 порт, посмотри, какой отлуп идёт при соединении телнетом, и как меняются счётчики у интерфейсов.

Comment: *я могу посмотреть её содержимое сам по ссылке ftp: // мойIP* Имеется в виду - с той же станции. где ФТП-сервер, по внешнему адресу работает, или с другой станции. но при своей учётной записи?

Comment: @Akina я на своём ПК сделал FTP сервер и с этого же ПК с этой же учётки  могу посмотреть его содержимое, порт 21 слушается приложением svchost.exe

Comment: @Akina в фаерволе только 3 разрешения добавил 
- FTP сервер (входящий трафик),   
- Трафик FTP-сервера в пассивном режиме,  
- трафик FTP-сервера (исходящий трафик)

Comment: А что снаружи telnet сообщает на `o твой_IP 21`? И что показывают счётчики пакетов/байтов на интерфейсах?

Comment: @Akina понятия не имею что он сообщает и как это узнать

Comment: @Akina кстати, а зачем юзеров создавать, ссылки недостаточно?

Comment: FTP не работает без авторизации (хотя бы анонимной - причём анонимусу по дефолту мало что дозволено). Так уж он устроен...

Comment: @Akina я добавил разрешения на чтение анонимусам и создал юзера со своим паролем, но по ссылочке всёравно никто посмотреть мою папку не может а за юзера с я и сам не могу посмотреть